# How does a complex exponential turn into the sinc function?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Suppose I have a complex variable $j$ such that we have

$f(u) = \frac{1}{ju}[e^{\frac{ju}{2}} - e^{\frac{-ju}{2}}]$.

Could somebody please explain how this turns into a sinc function ?

I know I have to apply [Euler's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) $e^{jx} = \cos(x) + j\sin(x)$.

So applying the formula to $f(u) =  \frac{1}{ju} [ (\cos(\frac{u}{2}) + j\sin(\frac{u}{2})) - (\cos(-\frac{u}{2}) + j\sin(-\frac{u}{2}))]$

$=  \frac{1}{ju} [ (\cos(\frac{u}{2}) + j\sin(\frac{u}{2})) - (\cos(\frac{u}{2}) - j\sin(-\frac{u}{2})) ]$

$=  \frac{1}{ju} [   j\sin(\frac{u}{2}))  + j\sin(\frac{u}{2})]$

$=  \frac{1}{ju} [  2j\sin(\frac{u}{2})]$

$=  \frac{1}{u} [  2\sin(\frac{u}{2})]$

But how does this become the [sinc function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last expression is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{\sin u/2}{u/2}$ which is equal to $sinc(u/2)$. Is this what you were looking for?