# With regards to finding a Fourier transform of a window function, how do I arrive at the sinc function?

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-numbers, fourier-transform

I have a follow up to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999337/how-does-a-complex-exponential-turn-into-the-sinc-function) regarding the derivation of a sinc function from a complex exponential, because I haven't been able to figure out how the introduction of a scaling factor will affect the Euler's formula. Can anyone please help?

The window function is:
 \begin{align}g(t) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if |t| < $\frac{1}{2a}$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

So the Fourier transform is:

\begin{align}
\int_{-1/2a}^{1/2a}e^{-j\omega t} dt
&= \frac{1}{j\omega}[e^{j\omega/2a}-e^{-j\omega/2a}]\\
&=  \frac{1}{j\omega}[\cos(\frac{\omega}{2a})+j\sin(\frac{\omega}{2a})-\cos(\frac{\omega}{2a})+j\sin(\frac{\omega}{2a})]\\
&= \frac{1}{j\omega}[2j\sin(\frac{\omega}{2a})]\\
&= \frac{\sin(\frac{\omega}{2a})}{\frac{w}{2}}
\end{align}

How do I get to the sinc function?

Comment: your question is not clear the linked question has already an accepted answer what do you want to know?

Comment: $ \frac{\sin(\frac{\omega}{2a})}{\frac{w}{2}}=  \frac{1}{a}\frac{\sin(\frac{\omega}{2a})}{\frac{w}{2a}} =  \frac{1}{a}\text{sinc}\frac{\omega}{2a}$

Comment: @James The linked question only had the answer to that specific problem. If I work it out in the exact same way I don't get to a step in which the $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ form is available.